# How can I exit of process "Speaker" in Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code in Node.JS:

```
textToSpeech.synthesize(synthesizeParams, function(err, response){
  if(err){
      console.log(err);
  }
  else{ 

    fs.writeFile('output.wav', response, 'binary', err => {
      var file  = fs.createReadStream('output.wav');
      reader.on('format', function (format) {
      reader.pipe(new Speaker(format));

      });
file.pipe(reader);
    });
  }

});
```

When the Speaker ends to talk, I have this problem: 
`[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...`

I'm using Nodemon. How can I fix that? Thanks

Comment: Looks like you need to implement a listener to `end` (or `finish` or `done` - depends on the interface of the API) event on the reader. i.e. `reader.on('end',...)`

Comment: @alfasin Could you help me with one example?

Comment: You don't show us what is `reader` is it's a bit difficult... check the APIs of whatever library you're using for `reader`

Comment: hey @Ale99, so this nodemon message you gave us is the default one, there should be additional log before that message, but if you cant see it, try replicating the problem running with node and give us the error message.

Comment: @alfasin this is my reader and another things: `var wav = require('wav');var Speaker = require('speaker'); var reader = new wav.Reader();`